# unattended upgrades removes packages

Tags: debian, unattended-upgrades

I've got unattended upgrades configured on my system. Every so often emails come in that a reboot is required. Yesterday after I rebooted my system to complete an upgrade, only to find that mysql-server had been removed from my system. /etc/init.d/mysql did still exist, but the mysqld and mysqld_secure executables were nowhere to be found. I've had this before with a different package.

How can I figure out why this happened, and how to prevent this in the future?

The first email that said I needed to reboot (5th of Oct):

```
Unattended upgrade returned: True

Warning: A reboot is required to complete this upgrade.

Packages that were upgraded:
 dnsmasq dnsmasq-base linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 linux-headers-amd64 
 linux-image-amd64 linux-libc-dev 
Packages with upgradable origin but kept back:
 python-reportbug reportbug 

Unattended-upgrades log:
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
Packages that will be upgraded: dnsmasq dnsmasq-base linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64 linux-libc-dev
Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'
All upgrades installed


cat unattended-upgrades-dp
kg.log
Log started: 2018-10-05  06:30:11
Reading changelogs...
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.16.0-7-amd64.
(Reading database ... 184176 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-7-amd64_3.16.59-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-7-amd64 (3.16.59-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../dnsmasq-base_2.72-3+deb8u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dnsmasq-base (2.72-3+deb8u4) over (2.72-3+deb8u3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../dnsmasq_2.72-3+deb8u4_all.deb ...
Unpacking dnsmasq (2.72-3+deb8u4) over (2.72-3+deb8u3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86_3.16.59-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 (3.16.59-1) over (3.16.57-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-7-common.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-7-common_3.16.59-1_amd64.deb 
...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-7-common (3.16.59-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-7-amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-7-amd64_3.16.59-1_amd64.deb .
..
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-7-amd64 (3.16.59-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-amd64_3.16+63+deb8u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-amd64 (3.16+63+deb8u3) over (3.16+63+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-amd64_3.16+63+deb8u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-amd64 (3.16+63+deb8u3) over (3.16+63+deb8u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_3.16.59-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.59-1) over (3.16.57-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.22-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-7-amd64 (3.16.59-1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-7-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-7-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-7-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-5-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-5-amd64
done
Setting up dnsmasq-base (2.72-3+deb8u4) ...
Setting up dnsmasq (2.72-3+deb8u4) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides
Setting up linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 (3.16.59-1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-7-common (3.16.59-1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-7-amd64 (3.16.59-1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-7-amd64
Setting up linux-headers-amd64 (3.16+63+deb8u3) ...
Setting up linux-image-amd64 (3.16+63+deb8u3) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.59-1) ...
Log ended: 2018-10-05  06:36:20

Log started: 2018-10-06  06:29:57
Reading changelogs...
(Reading database ... 198718 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7) over (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7) over (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7) ...
Setting up git (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7) ...
Log ended: 2018-10-06  06:30:17

Log started: 2018-10-09  06:38:14
Reading changelogs...
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 198718 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwbclient0_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.deb .
..
Unpacking libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg
-0+deb8u9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../samba-vfs-modules_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.
deb ...
Unpacking samba-vfs-modules (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-
0+deb8u9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../samba-dsdb-modules_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64
.deb ...
Unpacking samba-dsdb-modules (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg
-0+deb8u9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.deb .
..
Unpacking python-samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb
8u9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../samba-libs_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0
+deb8u9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../samba_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9) ..
.
Preparing to unpack .../samba-common-bin_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.d
eb ...
Unpacking samba-common-bin (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0
+deb8u9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../samba-common_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_all.deb ...
Unpacking samba-common (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb
8u9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
Setting up libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
Setting up samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
Setting up samba-vfs-modules (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
Setting up samba-dsdb-modules (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
Setting up python-samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
Setting up samba-common (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
Setting up samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides
Preparing to unpack .../samba_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.deb ...     
Unpacking samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9) ..
.                                                                         
Preparing to unpack .../samba-common-bin_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_amd64.d
eb ...                                                                    
Unpacking samba-common-bin (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0
+deb8u9) ...                                                              
Preparing to unpack .../samba-common_2%3a4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10_all.deb ...
Unpacking samba-common (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) over (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb
8u9) ...                                                                  
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...                            
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...                       
Setting up libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...               
Setting up samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...                 
Setting up samba-vfs-modules (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...                
Setting up samba-dsdb-modules (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...               
Setting up python-samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...                     
Setting up samba-common (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...                     
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...                 
Setting up samba (2:4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10) ...                            
insserv: warning: script 'K01gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides    
insserv: warning: script 'gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides       
insserv: warning: script 'K01gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides    
insserv: warning: script 'gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides       
insserv: warning: script 'K01gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides    
insserv: warning: script 'gitrunner' missing LSB tags and overrides       
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...                    
Log ended: 2018-10-09  06:38:49                                           

Log started: 2018-10-19  06:36:38                                         
Reading changelogs...                                                     
(Reading database ... 198718 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../libxenstore3.0_4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...   
Unpacking libxenstore3.0:amd64 (4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1) over (4.4.4lts1-0+deb8
u1) ...                                                                   
Preparing to unpack .../libxen-4.4_4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...       
Unpacking libxen-4.4:amd64 (4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1) over (4.4.4lts1-0+deb8u1) 
...                                                                       
Setting up libxenstore3.0:amd64 (4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1) ...                  
Setting up libxen-4.4:amd64 (4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1) ...                      
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...                    
Log ended: 2018-10-19  06:36:49




cat unattended-upgrades.lo
g
2018-10-02 06:49:15,627 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-02 06:49:15,628 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-02 06:49:15,629 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-02 06:49:15,629 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-02 06:49:26,262 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-03 06:32:11,773 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-03 06:32:11,788 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-03 06:32:11,788 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-03 06:32:11,789 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-03 06:32:19,785 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-04 06:33:26,814 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-04 06:33:26,828 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-04 06:33:26,829 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-04 06:33:26,830 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-04 06:33:34,612 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-05 06:29:45,944 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-05 06:29:45,960 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-05 06:29:45,961 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-05 06:29:45,961 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-05 06:30:11,710 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: dnsmasq dnsma
sq-base linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86 linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64 l
inux-libc-dev
2018-10-05 06:30:11,719 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgr
ades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'
2018-10-05 06:36:20,225 INFO All upgrades installed
2018-10-06 06:29:46,532 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-06 06:29:46,553 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-06 06:29:46,554 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-06 06:29:46,554 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-06 06:29:56,999 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: git git-man
2018-10-06 06:29:57,014 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgr
ades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'
2018-10-06 06:30:17,488 INFO All upgrades installed
2018-10-07 06:41:12,535 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-07 06:41:12,550 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-07 06:41:12,551 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-07 06:41:12,551 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-07 06:41:20,226 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-08 06:28:51,144 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-08 06:28:51,154 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-08 06:28:51,154 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-08 06:28:51,154 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-08 06:28:58,885 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-09 06:37:58,582 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-09 06:37:58,596 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-09 06:37:58,596 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-09 06:37:58,596 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-09 06:38:14,105 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libwbclient0 
python-samba samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-
libs samba-vfs-modules
2018-10-09 06:38:14,122 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgr
ades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'
2018-10-09 06:38:49,880 INFO All upgrades installed
2018-10-10 06:54:43,531 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-10 06:54:43,544 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-10 06:54:43,544 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-10 06:54:43,545 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-10 06:54:51,584 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-11 06:43:58,837 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-11 06:43:58,848 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-11 06:43:58,848 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-11 06:43:58,848 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-11 06:44:06,742 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-12 06:35:55,164 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-12 06:35:55,181 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-12 06:35:55,182 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-12 06:35:55,183 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-12 06:36:02,945 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-13 06:38:50,353 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-13 06:38:50,390 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-13 06:38:50,391 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-13 06:38:50,391 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-13 06:38:58,083 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-14 06:25:33,379 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-14 06:25:33,389 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-14 06:25:33,389 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-14 06:25:33,389 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-14 06:25:41,153 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-15 06:42:17,024 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-15 06:42:17,034 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-15 06:42:17,034 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-15 06:42:17,034 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-15 06:42:24,758 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-16 06:25:34,411 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-16 06:25:34,419 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-16 06:25:34,419 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-16 06:25:34,420 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-16 06:25:42,376 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-17 06:37:46,028 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-17 06:37:46,041 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-17 06:37:46,041 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-17 06:37:46,041 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-17 06:37:53,972 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-18 06:53:59,844 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2018-10-18 06:53:59,855 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2018-10-18 06:53:59,855 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-10-18 06:53:59,856 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2018-10-18 06:54:07,744 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: 
2018-10-15 06:42:17,034 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']                                           
2018-10-15 06:42:24,758 INFO Packages that will be upgraded:              
2018-10-16 06:25:34,411 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:                
2018-10-16 06:25:34,419 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:                
2018-10-16 06:25:34,419 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script          
2018-10-16 06:25:34,420 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']                                           
2018-10-16 06:25:42,376 INFO Packages that will be upgraded:              
2018-10-17 06:37:46,028 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:                
2018-10-17 06:37:46,041 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:                
2018-10-17 06:37:46,041 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script          
2018-10-17 06:37:46,041 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']                                           
2018-10-17 06:37:53,972 INFO Packages that will be upgraded:              
2018-10-18 06:53:59,844 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:                
2018-10-18 06:53:59,855 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:                
2018-10-18 06:53:59,855 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script          
2018-10-18 06:53:59,856 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']                                           
2018-10-18 06:54:07,744 INFO Packages that will be upgraded:              
2018-10-19 06:36:28,924 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:                
2018-10-19 06:36:28,926 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:                
2018-10-19 06:36:28,926 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script          
2018-10-19 06:36:28,927 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']                                           
2018-10-19 06:36:38,535 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libxen-4.4 li
bxenstore3.0                                                              
2018-10-19 06:36:38,544 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgr
ades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'                                        
2018-10-19 06:36:49,426 INFO All upgrades installed                       
2018-10-20 06:41:54,563 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:                
2018-10-20 06:41:54,573 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:                
2018-10-20 06:41:54,574 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script          
2018-10-20 06:41:54,575 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']                                           
2018-10-20 06:42:02,428 INFO Packages that will be upgraded:              
2018-10-21 06:27:41,988 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:                
2018-10-21 06:27:41,991 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:                
2018-10-21 06:27:41,992 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script          
2018-10-21 06:27:41,992 INFO Allowed origins are: ['origin=Debian,codename
=jessie,label=Debian-Security']                                           
2018-10-21 06:27:49,725 INFO Packages that will be upgraded:


cat apt/history.log                           

Start-Date: 2018-10-05  06:30:14
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-3.16.0-7-common:amd64 (3.16.59-1, automatic), linux
-image-3.16.0-7-amd64:amd64 (3.16.59-1, automatic), linux-headers-3.16.0-7
-amd64:amd64 (3.16.59-1, automatic)
Upgrade: dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.72-3+deb8u3, 2.72-3+deb8u4), linux-image-am
d64:amd64 (3.16+63+deb8u2, 3.16+63+deb8u3), linux-headers-amd64:amd64 (3.1
6+63+deb8u2, 3.16+63+deb8u3), linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86:amd64 (3.16.57-2,
 3.16.59-1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.16.57-2, 3.16.59-1), dnsmasq:amd64 (2
.72-3+deb8u3, 2.72-3+deb8u4)
End-Date: 2018-10-05  06:36:19

Start-Date: 2018-10-06  06:29:59
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: git-man:amd64 (2.1.4-2.1+deb8u6, 2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7), git:amd64 (2.
1.4-2.1+deb8u6, 2.1.4-2.1+deb8u7)
End-Date: 2018-10-06  06:30:16

Start-Date: 2018-10-09  06:38:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python-samba:amd64 (4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9, 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10),
 samba:amd64 (4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9, 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10), samba-dsdb-mod
ules:amd64 (4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9, 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10), samba-common-bin
:amd64 (4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9, 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10), samba-libs:amd64 (4.
2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9, 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10), libwbclient0:amd64 (4.2.14+dfs
g-0+deb8u9, 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10), samba-vfs-modules:amd64 (4.2.14+dfsg-0
+deb8u9, 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10), samba-common:amd64 (4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9,
 4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u10)
End-Date: 2018-10-09  06:38:49

Start-Date: 2018-10-19  06:36:40
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libxen-4.4:amd64 (4.4.4lts1-0+deb8u1, 4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1), libxen
store3.0:amd64 (4.4.4lts1-0+deb8u1, 4.4.4lts2-0+deb8u1)
End-Date: 2018-10-19  06:36:48
```

> grep mysql-server dpkg.log.*                  dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:31:45 upgrade mysql-server:all 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 7.
>   6.7-1debian8 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:45 status half-configured mysql-server:all 5.5 .60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:45
>   status unpacked mysql-server:all 5.5.60-0+d eb8u1
>   dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:45 status half-installed mysql-server:all
>   5.5. 60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:45 status half-installed mysql-server:all 5.5. 60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:45
>   status unpacked mysql-server:all 7.6.7-1deb ian8 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:31:45 status unpacked mysql-server:all 7.6.7-1deb ian8
>   dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:46 status installed mysql-server-5.5:amd64
>   5.5 .60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:46 remove mysql-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.60-0+deb8 u1  dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:31:46 status half-configured mysql-server-5.5:amd 64
>   5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:46 status half-installed mysql-server-5.5:amd6 4 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:49
>   status config-files mysql-server-5.5:amd64 
>   5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:49 status config-files mysql-server-5.5:amd64 
>   5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:49 status installed mysql-server-core-5.5:amd6 4 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:31:49 remove mysql-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.60-0
>   +deb8u1  dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:49 status half-configured mysql-server-core-5. 5:amd64 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:31:49 status half-installed mysql-server-core-5.5 :amd64
>   5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:49 status config-files mysql-server-core-5.5:a md64 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:31:49 status config-files mysql-server-core-5.5:a md64
>   5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:31:50 status config-files mysql-server-core-5.5:a md64 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:31:50 status not-installed mysql-server-core-5.5: amd64 
>   dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:35:05 status unpacked mysql-server:amd64
>   7.6.7-1d ebian8 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:35:05 remove mysql-server:amd64 7.6.7-1debian8  dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10
>   15:35:05 status half-installed mysql-server:amd64 7.
>   6.7-1debian8 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:35:05 status config-files mysql-server:amd64 7.6. 7-1debian8 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:35:05
>   status config-files mysql-server:amd64 7.6. 7-1debian8
>   dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:35:05 status config-files mysql-server:amd64
>   7.6. 7-1debian8 dpkg.log.1:2018-09-10 15:35:05 status not-installed mysql-server:amd64

Comment: it might help to see a log file from this period?

Comment: @BruceBecker sure, what logs could be useful?

Comment: probably things under `/var/log/apt/`  and`/var/log/unattended-upgrades/`

Comment: @BruceBecker I've added the logs that seem helpful to me.

Comment: Do you have any logs which actually mention MySQL packages?

Comment: @StephenKitt I added a zgrep from dpkg logs.  Seems to me like it got uninstalled but not reinstalled?

Comment: Yes, it looks that way, but it happened on September 10 — do you still have the `unattended-upgrades` logs from then?